# Qt5 get mjpeg stream from LAN

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I want to use QNetworkAccessManager get mjpeg stream from specify URL but I am failed.

This is my code :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    webCam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(webCam,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(replySteamFinish(QNetworkReply*)));
    QString cam = "http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream";
    QNetworkRequest req;
    req.setUrl(cam);
    webCam->get(req);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::replySteamFinish(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
        qDebug() << data;
    /*I just test whether receive the mjpeg stream data.*/
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << reply->error();
    }
}
```

I am trying to receive mjpeg stream data,but qDebug() did't work,nothing output.
When I put "http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream" in chrome, the web display the mjpeg stream fluent.

How should i fix it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I use QTcpSocket solve the problem.

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
        tcpSocket->connectToHost("192.168.1.1",8080);
        connect(tcpSocket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(tcpDataReceive()));

    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }


    void MainWindow::tcpDataReceive()
    {
        QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromHex(tcpSocket->readAll());
        qDebug() << data;
    }

    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        tcpSocket->write("GET /?action=stream\r\n\r\n");
    }
```

I think the mjpeg stream can not trigger SIGNAL finished,because the mjpeg data allways transfer.So, I choice use SIGNAL readyRead(). :)